# Node.js web browser with JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a `node` / `npm` module which would scrape the contents of a web page or a given URL and execute and evaluate it's JavaScript as a real-life web browser, including `XMLHttpRequest` object and alike?

I thought that [scraperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scraperjs) was the solution, but sadly it isn't.

All help very appreciated!

Comment: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)? I think the term you may be looking for is a headless browser, of which Phantom JS is one.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Headless browsers based on rendering engine:

- Chrome (blink)  => [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) or [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)
- Firefox (gecko) => [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/)
- Safari (webkit) => [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/)

Puppeteer is the official automation tool for Chrome. It only supports Chrome/Chromium browsers, (with experimental support for Firefox).

Playwright is an alternative to Puppeteer, with support for more browsers, written by the original creators of puppeteer, who jumped ship from Google to Microsoft. It supports Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers

Previous versions of my answer, included PhantomJS, SlimerJS,CasperJS and Nightmare all of which are no longer maintaned. For modern browsers, just use one of the above

Comment: What if I don't want to be headless?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer, since it was outdated. With Puppeteer, you don't have to be headless. It can be configured to launch a regular window.