# Scrape part of page that is not html

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to scrape [this site](http://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12).
I'm using Node.js and Phantom.js with Phantom.
This is my code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var loadInProgress = false;
var url = 'http://apps.who.int/flumart/Default?ReportNo=12';

(async function() {
    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });
    await page.on('onConsoleMessage', function(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    });
    await page.on('onLoadStarted', function() {
        loadInProgress = true;
        console.log('Load started...');
    });
    await page.on('onLoadFinished', function() {
        loadInProgress = false;
        console.log('Load end');
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    await console.log('STATUS:', status);

    const content = await page.property('content');
    await console.log('CONTENT:', content);

    // submit
    await page.evaluate(function() {
        document.getElementById('lblFilteBy').value = 'Country, area or territory'; //'WHO region';
        document.getElementById('lblSelectBy').value = 'Italy'; //'European Region of WHO';
        document.getElementById('lbl_YearFrom').value = '1995';
        document.getElementById('lbl_WeekFrom').value = '1';
        document.getElementById('lbl_YearTo').value = '2018';
        document.getElementById('ctl_list_WeekTo').value = '53';
        //console.log('SUBMIT:', document.getElementById('ctl_ViewReport'));
        document.getElementById('ctl_ViewReport').submit();
    });

    var result = await page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].outerHTML; // Problem here
    });
    await console.log('RESULT:', result);

    await instance.exit();
}());
```

I don't understand what this part (in red) of page is:
[image]

It's not HTML, how do I scrape the displayed data?

Thanks!

---

## EDIT 1

If I go to 'Network' tab of Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is a java applet. HTML source can tell you what type of object is it is.

Comment: @EriksKlotins Thanks but could you be more precise?

Comment: Somewhere in your html should be an <embed> or <object> tag. Look at the attributes, type and src should tell you the type/source of embedded object.

Comment: @EriksKlotins I did *View page source* from Chrome and I looked for both *embed* and *object*. He did not find anything...

Comment: Ok, I looked at the website. It is dynamically inserted MS Report Viewer. There is nothing you can scrape from html.

Comment: @EriksKlotins Mmm ok, so how I can scrape these information?

Comment: Check 'network' tab of chrome dev tools if there's an ajax request to intercept/read/fetch

Comment: @GillesQuenot Thanks. I update my main message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) request, check :

[image]

outlined in blue, it's the XHR request that you need to call yourself in your `phantom` script, and the ajax result outlined in red. In the header tab, you will see the *form data* sent via POST to the page.

Answer (score -1):

This is going to be hard. Take a look at this: [Node.js web browser with JavaScript execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971995/node-js-web-browser-with-javascript-execution)

Basically, you need a lib that simulates a browser with js execution and use that to render the report, then you can parse it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so Phantom.js is good for my goal. But how can I use that? I'm confusing

Comment: Looks like the data you are scraping are public domain anyway. Write to the WHO and politely ask for the data. Nothing to lose here.

Comment: What do you think [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) is ? It's all about js capable lib and it's a wrapper over `phantomjs`